# a doubt on group of semiprime (pq) order in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation

I have a doubt ${\color{red}{\text{(the red part below)}}}$ in Dummit&Foote's Abstract Algebra on page136 :

> Assume $G$ is a group of order $pq$ , where $p$ and $q$ are primes (not necessarily distinct) with $p\leq q$ . If $p\nmid q-1$ , we prove $G$ is abelian.
>
> If every nonidentity element of $G$ has order $p$ , then the centralizer of every nonidentity element has index $q$ , so the class equation for $G$ reads
> $$
> pq=1+kq\ .
> $$
> This is impossible since $q$ divides $pq$ and $kq$ but not $1$ . Thus $G$ contains an element, $x$ , of order $q$ .
>
> Let $H=\langle x\rangle$ . Since $H$ has index $p$ and $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$ , the subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ by Corollary 5. Since $\color{red}{Z(G)=1}$ , we must have $\color{red}{C_G(H)=H}$ .

I do not know how can $Z(G)=1$ conclude that $C_G(H)=H$ . This is my idea: since $H$ is cyclic hence abelian then $H\leq C_G(H)$ , by Lagrange's Theorem we obtain $|H|=q\Big||C_G(H)|$ , and since $C_G(H)\leq G$ we have $|C_G(H)|\Big||G|=pq\Rightarrow|C_G(H)|=q\ \text{or}\ pq$ , i.e., $C_G(H)$ is either $H$ or $G$ . But how can we deduce that $C_G(H)\ne G$ ? Or is there a direct way to show $C_G(H)=H$ ?